# Problem retrieving Dynamics CRM custom fields for integration in ADF

Tags: dynamics-crm, azure-data-factory

I am doing data integration from Dynamics CRM to Azure SQL Database using Azure Data Factory. I am unable to fetch the custom fields 
created in Dynamics CRM for doing the mapping in integration. Please help me with the solution for the above.

Comment: how are you fetching data from crm? Are you directly firing query against database i.e sql or are you using Dynamics crm webapi or you are using c# organization service to retrieve data.

Comment: I am using Dynamic CRM linked service(Service Uri,Authentication type = 'Office365') and select entity as a source.

Answer (score 0):

We ran pretty hard into the limitations of the Dynamics connector of Azure Data Factory v2. The ADF Dynamics connector does not expand the fields and requires a way too big rewrite of our current logic. Either with an entity selection or FetchXML, same results.

We were using SSIS + Cozyroc that did expand a lot of fields automatically. So we are back to using SSIS + Cozyroc. And since running custom components on SSIS-IR is... challenging we are also back to running SSIS on-premise.